# Linq query to db with dynamic where parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, wildcard

I have a table with data about cities: 
In a search input field the user types an arbitrary number of chars then presses "search" button.
There is also another field where the user can enter the state via a dropdownlist.

Pressing the search button triggers an ajax call to a server controller which receives both the starting chars of the name and the two chars of the state.

The controller should return the list of cities with name starting with the supplied chars.
If the state is passed, the list should contain only those cities whose name starts with the supplied chars AND that are situated in the state.

If the state is not passed all matching cities are returned regardless of the state.

I cannot find a way to write a single Linq statement, because I do not know how to write the part of the query for the state: 
Currently I do this:

```
public ActionResult selectCity(string searchString, string stateCode)
{
    List<CityViewModel> mylist = new List<CityViewModel>();
    IQueryable<City> mycities = null;

    if (stateCode == "")
    {
        mylist = (from c in db.Cities
                    where c.name.StartsWith(searchString)
                    select c);
    }
    else
    {
        mylist = (from c in db.Cities
                    where ((c.name.StartsWith(searchString)) &&
                          (c.stateCode == stateCode))
                    select c);
    }

    <snip>
    .....
    .....
    </snip>

   return PartialView("_selComune",elenco);
}
```

I can't believe that there isn't a way to do this with a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You want to *say*: if `stateCode` is empty or it matches `City.stateCode` then include it in result moreover `City.Name` must always begin with `searchString`. In code:

```
var mylist = 
    from c in db.Cities
    where 
        c.name.StartsWith(searchString) 
        && (stateCode == "" || c.stateCode == stateCode)
    select c;
```

Roughly equivalent to this SQL (assuming parameters with proper syntax are provided):

```
SELECT * FROM Cities
WHERE name LIKE @searchString AND (@stateCode = '' OR stateCode = @stateCode)
```

SQL Server will optimize second comparison away if first condition is always satisfied (just check Query Execution Plan).

---

<sub>I think it's a typo writing code example but `myList` isn't `List<City>` unless you also add `ToList()` to your LINQ query.</sub>

Comment: ... as usual, the answer is simple and straightforward; why bother with wildcards when we have "AND" and "OR".... Thanks for remembering me this golden rule

Answer (score 1):

Adriano Repetti's answer allows you to write a single query to handle "nullable" parameters but sometimes it has performance drawbacks, translated in SQL the kind of query may prevent indexes to work.

Please note that the following will also work and build the exact needed query on sql side, with only a bit of more code on LINQ side :

```
    mylist = (from c in db.Cities
              where c.name.StartsWith(searchString)
              select c);

    if (stateCode != "")
    {
        mylist = mylist.Where(c.stateCode == stateCode);
    }
```

This kind of construct won't replace previous "where" content, it will add any new terms combining them with a "and" operator.

IQeryable is made to allow you to built it in many different lines, not a single one like you did in your code sample.